# Объясните пожалуйста код с проверкой условия имеющий следующию конструкцию

Tags: c++, if

У меня есть следующий код в теле функции идет следующее условие:

```
...
if(--var)
{
function(int a, bool b);
function(int a, bool c);
}
...
```

и вторая конструкция

```
...
if(started)
{
...}
...
```

Какое условие проверяет моя программа?

Comment: Код очень расплывчатый. Не с компилируется никак. Ошибка в коде, где **function** фигурирует.

Comment: function в теле условия. вопрос не об этом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (--var) { ... }
```

можно прочесть так:

```
var = var - 1;
if (var != 0) { ... }
```

Comment: если в проверки условия стоит переменная без инкремента и декремента? Например: ...if(var)...

Comment: @NoNoJS приведение типов. Приводится к bool а там уже по сути проверка на 0 (для чисел), на null (для указателей) ну или чего там программист захотел (для своего класса)

Comment: Ну так вторая строчка - `if (var != 0)`